Frobenius method with one regular singular point and one irregular
I'm trying to solve the following ODE:
$$
-(\frac{A}{(1-z)z^4}-\frac{B}{z^4(1-z)^2}+\frac{C }{(1-z)z^2})R(r)+\frac{1}{1-z}R'(r)+R''(r)
$$
Clearly, 0 is an irregular singular point and z=1 is a singular point. I'm trying to apply Frobenius method to get the solution in $z=1$ with the ansatz:
$$
(1-z)^\alpha\sum^\infty_{k=0}c_k(1-z)^k
$$
But when I get the indicial equation I obtain a value for $\alpha$ that depends on $z$. Is that possible?
